# Disable link to copied smart objects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, layer-style, smartobject

I have several smart objects I want to duplicate and preserve the layer style.  However, when I modify one of the objects it also changes every copied smart object to match the modified one.  Is there a way to use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and another shortcut to remove the link so each smart object will have its own editable capabilities?  I am trying to prevent having to copy all the layer styles and add them to each smart object.  Per search the only reference I found was [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5194/nesting-photoshop-smart-objects-without-losing-the-link-between-them) but it covered how to and that is not what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time the only option is `right click > New Smart Object via Copy` but since I needed to do this several times I created a custom shortcut in `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts` or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.  To modify the `New Smart Object via Copy` look under `Layer > SmartObject>`.

**NOTE:** If you duplicate a folder with several of the smart objects inside it will still link all smart objects to the original copy.

[image]

Comment: I've tried to duplicate via copy, but found that it relinks everything to that new .psb file. I also loose the transformations in the original smart object layer when I try to replace content. Is there a way to copy a smart object, keep its transformation/etc. properties, and have a separate .psb file that isn't linked to the other instances of the original smart object? Not sure if that needs it's own post.