# How can I duplicate smart objects and make them separate in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, cs6

In **Photoshop** I can copy and paste Illustrator paths as a **smart object**, and then double click this smart object to edit it in **Illustrator**.

When I duplicate this smart object (say to change the colour scheme of a logo I'm designing and offer a client multiple colour schemes) and edit the newly created smart object, BOTH objects change.

It's one of those Adobe quirks where I'm not quite sure if it's a feature or a bug :)

Anyway, in order to offer separate colour schemes of a logo in one `.psb` file, I'd like to know how to edit derivative smart objects independently of each other :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable link to copied smart objects](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18665/disable-link-to-copied-smart-objects) if not what you are asking hope it helps.

Answer (score 39):

1. Right click on smart object layer
2. Click **"new smart layer from copy"**

The new layer that's generated can be edited independently of its **"parent"**.

Comment: In Photoshop CC, this function has been renamed to "New Smart Object via Copy"

Comment: Did not work for me. I selected the smart object in the layers menu, then in the top menu bar I select Layers > New > Layer via Copy. Editing the newly created layer updates the other one...

Answer (score 4):

When a smart object is duplicated as a new layer (<kbd>command</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd>) it remains linked or nested with original layer. These layers can be given any type of effect. However when a `smart object` is double clicked it opens into a new window and any editing in this layer will make similar changes into the duplicated layer.

If one wants to edit all the smart object separately without affecting others all the layers should be duplicated as new smart object via `copy`. This command is available under `layer menu` in smart object, on the drop down menu in the layer or right clicking on **smart object**.